# Text between SQL unions in Dropdownlist - ASP.net c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, dropdown, union-all

I have a SQL query which brings back staff which are most important and should appear at top of the dropdown list, then all other staff below this.

The query is built using unions to collect both queries together.

I would like to have text at the top of the dropdownlist and text in between the unions.  Is this possible?

E.G "Preferred Staff Members" as the top and "All Other Staff members" to separate the two unions

```
select DISTINCT e.EMPLOY_REF, e.FORENAME + ' ' + e.SURNAME as Name
from EMPLOYEE_TABLE e

where e.ID = @ID
and e.DATE_LEFT IS NULL or e.DATE_LEFT > GETDATE()

UNION ALL

select DISTINCT e.EMPLOY_REF, e.FORENAME + ' ' + e.SURNAME as Name
from EMPLOYEE_TABLE e
where e.DATE_LEFT IS NULL or e.DATE_LEFT > GETDATE()
ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: consider using two dropdowns. this may be opinion-based, IMO it is not good user interface design practice. And it creates need for additional input validation logic, as you would not want the user to be able to actually choose the value of "Preferred Staff Members".

Comment: You're better off doing two queries and then adding additional list items in your code layer because it's something specific to display and not data. Imagine reusing that query elsewhere and suddenly you have additional non-data data

Answer (score 1):

You can add a dummy select in between

```
SELECT 'Name 1' AS A, 1 AS sortOrder
UNION ALL
SELECT '----' AS B, 2 AS sortOrder
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Name 2' AS C, 3 AS sortOrder
ORDER BY sortOrder, A
```

In your case this would look something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.EMPLOY_REF, e.FORENAME + ' ' + e.SURNAME as Name, 1 AS sortOrderFROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE e
UNION ALL
SELECT '----', '----' AS B, 2 AS sortOrder
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT e.EMPLOY_REF, e.FORENAME + ' ' + e.SURNAME as Name, 3 AS sortOrderFROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE e
ORDER BY sortOrder, Name
```

Comment: In this case though, the sorting will move the '-----' to the top and not keep it in the correction positio

Comment: Updated my answer, you can add an extra column for the sorting of the names.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet may be to include some sort of Sort Order field in each of your queries. Maybe an identifier such as an astrick marking them preferred.

```
-- Preferred Employees
SELECT '* ' + NameInfo, 1
FROM Employees
WHERE YaddaYadda

UNION

-- Normal Employees
SELECT NameInfo, 2
FROM Employees
WHERE YaddaYadda
```

Then you can use a sort by in your code to sort first by the sort order, then by name.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try following

```
SELECT 0, 'Preferred Staff Members' 
UNION ALL
select DISTINCT e.EMPLOY_REF, e.FORENAME + ' ' + e.SURNAME as Name
from EMPLOYEE_TABLE e

where e.ID = @ID
and e.DATE_LEFT IS NULL or e.DATE_LEFT > GETDATE()

UNION ALL

SELECT -1, 'All Other Staff members' 
UNION ALL


select DISTINCT e.EMPLOY_REF, e.FORENAME + ' ' + e.SURNAME as Name
from EMPLOYEE_TABLE e
where e.DATE_LEFT IS NULL or e.DATE_LEFT > GETDATE()
ORDER BY Name
```

You can then easily identify which option is selected by (0 or -1)